# Unable to get a reference for an array index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to delete the list item from the array `Tasks[]` when the delete button is clicked but I am unable to generate a reference for the specific index of `Tasks[]`. I am a newbie to react, infact I recently started learning react.

Here's my code
App.js

```
type hereimport React, { Component } from "react";
import Overview from "./OverView";
import uniqid from "uniqid";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      task: {
        text: '', 
        taskno: 0,
        id: uniqid()
      },
      tasks: [],
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      task: {
        text: e.target.value,
        taskno: this.state.task.taskno,
        id: this.state.task.id,
      },
    });
  };
  deleteTask = (e) => {
    console.log(this.state.task.taskno)
    // this.setState({
    //   // tasks: this.state.tasks.filter(this.state.tasks[task.id])
    // })
    
  };

  onSubmitTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(this.state.task),
      
      task: {
        text: '',
        taskno: this.state.task.taskno + 1, 
        id: uniqid()
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { task, tasks} = this.state;
    // const {deleteTask} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitTask}>
          <label htmlFor="taskInput">Enter task</label>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={task.text}
            type="text"
            id="taskInput"
          />
          <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
        </form>
        <Overview tasks={tasks} deleteTask={this.deleteTask} />
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here's Overview.js

```
import React from "react";

const Overview = (props) => {
  
  const { tasks,deleteTask} = props;

  return (
     
    <ul>
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return(
        <div>
       <li key={task.id}>{task.taskno} : {task.text}   <button onClick={deleteTask}> Delete</button>  </li>
       
        </div>)
      })}
     
      
    </ul>
  
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

So far I have been able to add the delete button and register a click on the delete button but I am struck there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Deleting current task

There are multiple ways to make this work, but I will choose the easiest one.
Each task has a unique `id`, and you can use it and pass it down to the delete function, then filter out all the elements which are not the same as the passed down `id`. This way, whenever you delete a task, you can keep all other tasks and remove the current one from the list.

#### Codes

```html
...
<button onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}> Delete</button>
...
```

```js
...
deleteTask = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       tasks: prevState.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id)
    }))
  };
...
```